# Web scraping data which refreshes every minute

Tags: excel, web-scraping

I am trying to extract some data from this website which refreshes every minute. I have tried researching about web scraping and tried chrome extensions but none seem to work for me.

Some background information about the website: it is a website where people go to monitor bid prices for COE (certificate of entitlement for cars in Singapore). Every alternate Wednesday, from 1430 to 1600, I would have to manually copy and paste the data into an Excel spreadsheet before it refreshes every minute.

Details for COE

[image]

I have attached screenshots to illustrate further.
This is the website to scrape; https://www.onemotoring.com.sg/1m/coe/coeDetail.html

Answer (score -3):

You can get a very low cost with AWS Lambda with node-js.

Create a Lambda function and trigger it at your cron schedule you want to crawl the website. You can use library like

https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler

to simplify crawling.

Also,

To get the exact nodes in the page use serverside jquery or any progressive script that can extract elements from the crawled page.

Once you have the details, you can store them under DynamoDB which is a nosql with very low latency.

You can use,
ODM like https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels to access DynamoDB with very less code.

Hope it helps.